# Did Daichi and Hana survive?

Tags: captain-earth

Yes, here we are fans of confusing anime endings, for one more episode of "Did them survive?" [[1]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/116/2808) [[2]](https://anime.stackexchange.com/search?q=survive).

So, did the love doves Daichi and Hana survive the explosion of the (huge) ego block of Robin Goodfellow (formerly Puck)?

My question comes in 2 parts. For the 2 possible situations. What happened to the 2 of them after the explosion occurred.

If they died, then how did it happen?

If they did survive, how was that possible?

Try to get sources and references to the anime, if not make your speculative point plausible and very airtight, thanks.

Comment: The last scene implies that they survive the explosion somehow, by phase shifting or something like that.

Comment: Very likely. When other characters phase-shifted (Moco, Tepei), they were outside this reality (maybe another dimension). And Tepei survived the Boosted Plasmagun (supposedly as strong or stronger than an ego block explosion) while phase shifted. Since both had working Livlasters at the end, they could do that.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of research, it seems that they both did survive. In the same regard as to when Daichi fired the Boostedmagnum at the debris, supposedly killing Teppei, Daichi's Livlaster pulled the two into the same place, that Teppei was taken that let him survive the blast. It isn't very well explained, but I believe that the little girl with blue hair is Daichi's Livlaster in human form.

Answer (score 0):

As in the case of Teppei, his Livilaster teleported them onto a platform near Earth (Assumed from his comment about seeing the galaxy from this planet) the unnamed blue hair girl is his Livalaster in human form and helped Entrangled Jump them out of the explosion. It's obvious that Dachi is alive because he spoke at the very last 5 seconds Hana responded with, "Yeah." so that means she woke up from being unconscious. All in all it is a happy ending and they probably go back to meet their friends and family. I'll go read the manga and update this answer.