# When did Lelouch take the Code from his father?

Tags: code-geass

When I was just searching for theories for why people believe Lelouch is still alive, I found a [theory](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/147/45301) which says Lelouch took the Geass from his dad, so when he was killed he actually became immortal. But on re-watching the series I can't find any such scene where we see Lelouch taking the Code from his dad. Or did I miss something?

When I watched the anime for the first time, I remember it had extra scenes like Lelouch driving the cart, which wasn't present when I re-watched the series. I read that it was removed later.

So, did the writers remove the scene in which Lelouch takes the Code from his dad?
I am getting an impression that the writers had plans on keeping Lelouch alive, initially. They came out and said the ending was left ambiguous for the reader to interpret as they want, and then, they removed that scene and declared Lelouch is dead.

Comment: it's possible that the new movie coming out might give an answer however my belief is that the moment the second sigil appeared in Lelouch's other eye he had stolen the code because at that moment "God" was able to kill Charles. however a screenshot i have seen advertised for the new movie makes me believe the Code was not active until the Zero Requiem had been fulfilled

Comment: @Memor-X Well movies aren't taking place in anime universe but in the movie universe. As you can see sherly is alive in movies but dead in anime. While in the trailer she is alive so it is a sequel to movies. So answers presented in movies might not explain it. Also, geass cannot work on a person with the code so I thought it was a god who killed Charles. So not sure if Lelouch can force Charles to give his Code.

Comment: @Memor-X No, that's not correct. Lelouch never got a code. the show staff officially confirmed he was truly dead and not immortal. the show staff even explicitly denied that codes needed to activated through death. You should read the Code Geass Community Information Database. It has all the info. https://www.reddit.com/user/GeassedbyLelouch/comments/8hklfr/evaluating_code_theory_main_body_index/

Answer (score 3):

Lelouch never got Charles's code.
That was an old fan theory, but it was debunked by the community years ago.
The anime itself made it impossible and even the show staff have officially confirmed that Lelouch was truly dead.
So he never got a code or immortality.
There are also no scenes which show Lelouch as the cart driver. that's merely a fake fan-made video on youtube, it was never real. people made that to fool fans and to push their debunked conspiracy theory of him having a code.

All the official information regarding Lelouch's death can be found on the [Code Geass Community Information Database](https://www.reddit.com/user/GeassedbyLelouch/comments/8hklfr/evaluating_code_theory_main_body_index/). It has all the official statements, including sources, links, pictures, etc. It also shows how the anime made the fan theory impossible.

Here are some examples of official statements.

From "Geass Memories":
- *"Before I started writing the story of a person called Lelouch, I confirmed with Taniguchi-director something. That thing was that the end of Lelouch will be death."*
- *"At least he is aware of his sins and pays for them with his death."*
- *"This man called Lelouch will pay for his sins by his death. The story follows him till he finally make this decision."*

From the official guide book:
- *"For those two who bear the heavy sin known as killing their fathers, they share the belief that they can forgive each other by imposing the greatest punishments on themselves. Death for Lelouch who wishes for a tomorrow with his sister, life for Suzaku who wishes to atone for his sins through death."*

From [the remade epilogue](https://streamable.com/d8dji) from 2009 where they dropped the cart driver scene and replaced it with a brand new epilogue:
- *"A young man dies. He had the power to change the world, to create a new order. The world feared him, hated him. But, I know he died with a smile on his face. Only those who have realised their dream will truly understand that feeling of utter contentment. So, this is not a tragedy. And whenever I feel sad or cry at night, I sing a song. A song of man's making. Zero Requiem!"*

All sources and many more examples can be found in the above linked Database

Comment: could you please quote the elevents points of the post that support your answer. also i should point out that just as the end of the post you link to says, thigns can be retconned and [according to the wiki](https://codegeass.fandom.com/wiki/Code_Geass%3A_Lelouch_of_the_Re%3Bsurrection#Plot) *" Due to stopping the progression of the Sword of Akasha in C's World and 'killing' Charles Zi Britannia at the same time, Lelouch gains Code but fails to transition to it completely due to the abrupt stop in Charles's plans with Ragnarök that would have converted him to a functioning immortal"*

Comment: (cont.) though i will admit i have yet to see the new series yet and can not verify myself if what the wiki says is true about the plot summary

Comment: @Memor-X what are "elevents points"? In any case, the 4 movies form an alternate universe which isn't canon to the tv series. And the wiki is even very wrong there. C.C. herself first wonders about the possibility that has got a code, but then immediately dismisses that idea. Lelouch himself says he is uncertain about immortality. And the movie shows us that the new power he got is very different from the code.

Comment: sorry, i mean Relevant Points. you don't need to quote everything, just the relevant points about the code as currently you are telling people to "go to this link and read though all the stuff about how Lelouch is confirmed dead" when it would be simplier to quote the parts about just the code in the event that reddit goes down, that post is removed or any of the links that reddit posts links too